# How to delete one of the multiple audio tracks from a mkv?

Tags: audio, editing, video-editing, mkv, mixing

I want to make a clip from a movie that has an english track and a Chinese dub track. When I trim the video in any software it only gives me the Chinese track as the audio. How do I delete the Chinese dub track altogether so that after editing I'll have the video with the english track? Any websites or softwares?